# Android soft keyboard input method

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText where the input method is set to "text".
When the keyboard is opened, the initial typing option is letters, but there is, in the lower corner, the possibility to switch to numbers, as in the figure below:

[text-keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cpSd.png)

Is it possible to start this keyboard directly in numeric mode, like in the image below?

[number-keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppjxm.png)

Remembering that my EditText can receive texts too; I just want the first option to be numbers instead of letters.